# XML generated by WCF client is missing some elements

Tags: wcf, soap, xml-serialization, jax-ws

I am writing a WCF client to communicate with a JAX-WS web service. Basically communication with the service works. But when investigating the XML generated by the WCF client there are some elements missing. All the properties are correctly generated and I have set them in my code. I am new to WCF and web services in general so I have problems to analize what could be wrong here. What could cause the missing elements in the XML? The only thing I noticed all these missing properties have in common is that they are enumeration types. But other than that I found nothing. For example there is a enumeration for country codes. An entitity has 3 properties of that enumeration type. Only one of the 3 related elements is generated in the XML.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP discovered, when a WCF client (including proxy classes generated by the `XSD.exe` utility) imports an enumerator from the WSDL or XSD, the proxy also has a corresponding `bool` property. For an enumeration element named 'Foobar' there is also 'FoobarSpecified' which must be set to `true` or WCF will not serialize the data element.

This is still true 6 years after the question was asked, even when using the new WCF Client in .NET Core and Visual Studio 2017, and it isn't especially obvious, so I thought I'd promote the OP's comment response to wiki answer.

Comment: Sir, you have saved our lifes.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely occuring because WCF contracts treat enums differently. For data contracts you mark the class with a `DataContract` attribute and the members with a `DataMember` attribute. What's not as well known is that enums have their own attribute called `EnumMember` which WCF uses to serialize them properly.

There is an MSDN article called [Enumeration Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx) which goes over the usage in greater detail. The example code from the article shows how a contract with an enum should look:

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public string model;
    [DataMember]
    public CarConditionEnum condition;
}

[DataContract(Name = "CarCondition")]
public enum CarConditionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    New,
    [EnumMember]
    Used,
    [EnumMember]
    Rental,
    Broken,
    Stolen
}
```

Note that in their example (which I've included above) you can set just a subset of the enum values as part of the data contract if that's a requirement.

In addition to this any property that is not tagged with the `DataMember` attribute will not serialize over the wire. This should be the checklist to ensure that serialization works for WCF:

1. Check that classes are marked with the `DataContract` attribute.
2. Check that properties are marked with the `DataMember` attribute.
3. Check that the individual enum values are marked with the `EnumMember` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I generated the proxy and data classes automatically so shouldnt WCF take care of this? However, I edited Reference.cs manually and added the attributes you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: Is there error on the WCF endpoint you created or on the connection to the external JAX-WS Web Service? If it's the JAX-WS Web Service are you able to send the enumeration to it outside of WCF?

Comment: I found a solution. There are a few properties which have related properties that have to be set if you have assigned a value to them. For example there could be an element Foobar and another one IsFoobarSet. And only when IsFoobarSet = true the Foobar element will be created. Don't ask me why it is implemented that way. Seems pretty unusual to me, but I am new to that stuff so there might be a super logical reason for this.